# Creating curve controls with position relative to a selection in Maya with Python?

Tags: python, maya

I am still very new at coding and thought I would try scripting a tool from a tutorial by Chris Lesage which outlines a little softMod rig. So far I've been trying to put it together one step at a time like a lot of coding tutorials recommend.
https://chrislesage.com/posts/sliding-bulging-effects-with-softmods/

It is working ok, but I am curious how I can create the circles in this case being used as controllers but with their 'center' attribute relative to a selected vertex. I'm not sure what commands I should be looking

Ultimately I'm trying to make a softMod at a selected vertex, and have these controls created to animated the effects. I hope that makes sense. It's a fun learning exercise so far!

Thank you for any tips!
Alex

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm
from pymel.core import *

cmds.softMod( falloffRadius=10, envelope=1, falloffAroundSelection=True)

cntrlA = cmds.circle( nr=(0, 0, 1), c=(0, 0, 0), r=2, name="ControlA" )
cntrlB = cmds.circle( nr=(0, 0, 1), c=(0, 0, 0), r=1, name="ControlB" )

#Need to translate the curves above the specific surface or mesh

cmds.parentConstraint( 'ControlA', 'ControlB', maintainOffset=True )

cmds.spaceLocator(name="testLoc")

cmds.parentConstraint( 'ControlA', 'testLoc', maintainOffset=False )

cmds.connectAttr( 'testLoc.t', 'softMod1.falloffCenter' )
cmds.connectAttr( 'ControlB.t', 'softMod1Handle.translate' )
cmds.connectAttr( 'ControlB.r', 'softMod1Handle.rotate' )

#### This code worked to create the controls AND assign them to a variable

cmds.select( cntrlB) 
cmds.addAttr('ControlB', ln='softModENV', keyable=True, dv=1, min=0, max=1 )
cmds.addAttr('ControlB', ln='falloffRAD', keyable=True, dv=10, )

# Connect the attributes you made previously
cmds.connectAttr( 'ControlB.softModENV', 'softMod1.envelope' )
cmds.connectAttr( 'ControlB.falloffRAD', 'softMod1.falloffRadius' )

cmds.group( 'ControlA', 'ControlB', 'testLoc', 'softMod1Handle', n='softModGRP' )
```

Comment: use cmds.pointPosition or cmds.xform to get the position of the vertex.

Comment: I will try that, thanks for the suggestions!